# Make a particle system without SpriteKit (SKEmitterNode etc...)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, system, gravity, particles

I'm trying to make a "homemade" particle system like this: http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-4-particle-systems/
without using libraries like SpriteKit.
I started whit this Particle.h class:

```
typedef struct {
float x;
float y;
} Vector;

@interface Particle : NSObject {
    NSRect particle;
    NSBezierPath *pPath;
    Vector *position;
    Vector *velocity;
    Vector *aceleration;
    float lifespan;
}
```

But I don't know how to make a gravity behavior in my Custom view when i draw one particle.
Thank you in advice.

Comment: Can you answer the question "why"? It will probably be *incredibly* inefficient and slow! There is a reason these things are built-in.

Comment: The reason is I need to do this project for college, but don't know how to start...

Comment: You should make an update method for your system thatbwill take in to account the deltaTime since last update... and set posituons accordingly like : [self setPosition:CGPointMake(self.position.x + deltaTime*(_velocity.dx + _acceleration.dx*deltaTime), self.position.y + deltaTime*(_velocity.dy + acceleration.dy*deltaTime - _gravity*deltaTime))];